# Is it possible to call a AppDelegate method of objective C from swift code of same project

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I need to call my `AppDelegate` function of Objective-C from the Swift class of the same project. 
The function definition is in Objective-C `AppDelegate`.
I need to call from Swift class existing in the same project.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to call Objective-C code from Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24002369/how-to-call-objective-c-code-from-swift)

Comment: @iMHiteshSurani - read the question carefully, from appdelegate not from objective C file

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik Appdelegate file was written in objective C as mention in question.

Answer (score 2):

Create a Bridging Header file and add

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
```

Add your function definition in AppDelegate.m and function declaration

AppDelegate.m

```
- (NSString *)test {
    return @"test";
}
```

AppDelegate.h

```
- (NSString *)test;
```

In Swift file

```
if let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate {
    print(appDelegate.test())
}
```

Comment: if i import AppDelegate.h in bridgeheader i'm getting error that some of your pod file is missing.

Comment: Thanks for your support bro. but this not fixed my issue

Comment: No need to add #import "'AppDelegate.h" in the Bridging Header File,  simply use let myAppdelegateObj = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate & myAppdelegateObj.yourFunctionName() .

Comment: @Friend Use of undeclared type 'AppDelegate'

Comment: clean & build .

Comment: @Friend Have you tried it by running? How could the swift file know there is a class named AppDelegate without importing it in bridging header?

Comment: Yes, i am currently running it in my project.

Comment: Then you would've imported other objective c files which imports appdeletgate